# wpf shape doesn't stay on top using index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've attempted to use the index to set the red ellipse on top of the blue background but no matter what i changed it didn't affect its placement. How can i make it so the red dots appear in-front/on-top of the blue rectangle?

[image]

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                Cursor="Hand" 
                Background="LightBlue" 
                CornerRadius="4"
                Panel.ZIndex="0"
                Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Height="30"
                    MinWidth="100" 
                    Panel.ZIndex="5"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding VirtualName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Red" Height="16" Width="16"
                 Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-8,0,0" 
                 Panel.ZIndex="50"/>

        <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Red" Height="16" Width="16"
                 Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                 Panel.ZIndex="50"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use grid without any rows and add margin to the border which is the first element on the grid. Place the ellipses with VerticalAlignment to top and bottom and they will be rendered on top of the border.

```
<Grid>
    <Border Cursor="Hand" 
            Background="LightBlue" 
            CornerRadius="4"
            Margin="0 8"
            Padding="10,0,10,0">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" MinWidth="100" />
            <Label Content="{Binding VirtualName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Top" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Red" Height="16" Width="16"/>

    <Ellipse VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Red" Height="16" Width="16"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of your Canvas.ZIndex properties. They do appear on top based on the order you've placed them in the grid, so the z indices aren't going to affect anything.

The issue here is that the bottom ellipse gets clipped because it's in a row of height 8. Try setting its margin to `0,0,0,-8`, and you'll get your desired behavior.